# How can I put an array as the argument in OrmLite where clause?

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

I want to pass a few dates to this method, and get a few objects from the DB in return.

```
QueryBuilder<WorkDayDB, Long> queryBuilder =
    application.ormLiteDatabaseHelper.getWorkDayDBDao().queryBuilder();
Where where = queryBuilder.where();
try {
    where.eq("date", dates);
    return queryBuilder.prepare();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

However, the `where.eq("date", dates);` throws an exception, saying it needs a single `Date`, not an array of dates.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `eq` means `equals` which is specifically used for a single argument, whereas `in` (which is another method of `where` in OrmLite) allows for an array of arguments to be passed. This solved my problem.